# What is the navigation drawer icons size?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-design-library, android-navigationview

I need to know the correct size (artboard and content) for Navigation Drawer icons.

It doesn't say anything on the Navigation Drawer specs:
http://www.google.com.br/design/spec/patterns/navigation-drawer.html#navigation-drawer-specs

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.google.co.uk/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing

Comment: I can calculate the artboard size (which is 40 x 40dp), but what is the content size? Note that the navigation drawer icons are smaller than the "avatar icons".

Comment: Is there a way to edit the default navigation drawer icon size?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would vote up Balar's answer, but it is off by one small detail. The correct answer is that all small icons should be 24 x 24 **dp**.

Reference: https://material.io/guidelines/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-touch-target-size

Comment: An equivalent resource for Material Design can be found [**here**](http://www.google.at/design/spec/style/icons.html#icons-system-icons).

Comment: Links are broken. Correct one is https://material.io/archive/guidelines/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-sizing-by-increments as of 2021

Answer (score 24):

**For:**

```
mdpi : 24 x 24 px
hdpi : 36 x 36 px
xhdpi : 48 x 48 px
xxhdpi : 72 x 72 px
xxxhdpi : 96 x 96 px
```

**According to their ratios:**

```
mdpi : hdpi : xhdpi : xxhdpi : xxxhdpi= 1 : 1.5 : 2 : 3 : 4
```

**Update:**

Now google published Material icon design with more details.icons may be scaled down to 20dp with a trim area of 2dp surrounding the icon.

[image]

To learn more visit the [Material Design](https://material.google.com/style/icons.html#icons-product-icons) site.

Answer (score 9):

You can check the official implementation of [NavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/NavigationView.html) provided by the support design library.

If you see the code of NavigationMenuItemView it defines:

```
this.mIconSize = 
 context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(dimen.navigation_icon_size);
```

where:

```
<dimen name="navigation_icon_size">24dp</dimen
```

Answer (score 1):

the dimensions of those navigation icons are usually 24 x 24 pixels

Comment: Do you mean 24 x 24 dp? Do you know where I can find this info on the official documentation?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the icon size to set the dimensions of a view component you can use the Toolbar.Button.Navigation style. Here is an example where I create a fake navigation icon view.

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/vCoordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--CONTENT VIEW-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <!--FAKE TOOLBAR NAVIGATION ICON-->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/vToolbarNavigationIcon"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:src="@drawable/my_icon"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```